# IIS 6 Application Pool Identity permissions

Tags: iis, iis-6, asp.net, application-pools

Other questions have touched on this, but let's get a complete answer down:

1. What specific permissions are necessary for a generic IIS 6 site with a domain user as the app pool identity?
2. What specific permissions are necessary for an ASP.NET IIS 6 site with a domain user as the app pool identity?
3. Are there any tricks/shortcuts to applying these permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this article:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302396.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what the absolute "minimum" permissions are for an app pool identity.
But you'll definitely need the **Log on as a service** right.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ssehgal/archive/2009/06/23/running-iis6-app-pools-under-a-domain-account-identity.aspx